# OpenGL 3.3 texture mapping 3D objects

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I'm trying to texture a 3D pool table with two different textures, one for the table top and one for the legs and the walls. The table top is basically a 2D rectangle on which I applied some green texture and everything worked fine. On the other hand when I try to texture the cubes composing the table I run into some sampling or mapping problems.
This is my code:
create the vaos and map

```
  // Cube vertex data
float cubeVertices[ CUBE_NUM_VERTICES * VALS_PER_VERT ] = {
  -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
  -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
  -1.0,  1.0, -1.0 };

  // 12 triangles - 2 per face of the cube
unsigned int legWallIndices[CUBE_NUM_TRIS*3] = {
  0,1,2, 2,3,0,
  1,5,6, 6,2,1,
  5,4,7, 7,6,5,
  4,0,3, 3,7,4,
  3,2,6, 6,7,3,
  4,5,1, 1,0,4
};

float tableTopVertices[4 * VALS_PER_VERT] = {
  -2.5f, 0.26f, -5.0f,
  2.5f, 0.26f, -5.0f,
  2.5f, 0.26f, 5.0f,
  -2.5f, 0.26f, 5.0f,
};

unsigned int tableTopIndices[2*3] = {
  0,1,2, 2,3,0,
};

float tabletTopTexCoord[4 * VALS_PER_TEX] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};

float legWallTexCoord[8 * VALS_PER_TEX] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    // not working properly idk why
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

vertex shader

```
in vec2 green_tex_coord;
in vec2 wood_tex_coord;

out vec2 st1;
out vec2 st2;

void main(void)
{
  st1 = green_tex_coord;
  st2 = wood_tex_coord;
}
```

fragment shader

```
in vec2 st1;
in vec2 st2;

uniform sampler2D greenTexMap;
uniform sampler2D woodTexMap;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 topClr = vec4(0.04, 0.42, 0.1, 1.0);
  vec4 sideClr = vec4(0.5, 0.35, 0.05, 1.0);

  if (predicate){
      fragColour = topClr * texture(greenTexMap, st1);
  }else{
      fragColour = sideClr * texture(woodTexMap, st2);
  }
}
```

This is the result (the green texture is working but the wood one is not) [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfwB6.png)

If I remove `* texture(woodTexMap, st2)` the colour changes (it shows sideClr), this means the texture reaches the fragment but it is badly sampled or mapped. If I remove `sideClr *` the colour changes again showing a plain colour and not a texture (actually it looks like it samples the bottom left corner of my picture).

Am I mapping it the wrong way or is it a sampling problem?

Comment: Your vertex shader looks implausible. Where do you perform perspective transformations, for example?

Comment: For clarity's sake I removed all the stuff that is not strictly related to this problem, because everything else works fine

Comment: You can use only one sampler and simpler shader. Draw legs mesh with same settings as table top, just switch VB, IB and texture/sampler

Comment: Oh, yes, I guessed so but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible because this is my first try with textures. I will give it a try. Anyway I don't think this is related to the problem, is it?

Comment: @RobiNoob You should try to check your program by any of graphics debug software, like **RenderDoc**, **Intel GPA**, **nVidia nSight**.

Comment: Conditions in shaders are almost always a red flag, so Michael is right.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelNastenko and hidefromkgb for the hint, I will try. So there's nothing wrong with my texture coordinates?

Comment: @RobiNoob It's hard to tell. Array seems to be fine :-) You must setup it properly. It means you need to put more code for us to check. But, usually, there is some minor mistake, so, check your program with RenderDoc or GPA.

Comment: Uhm, why do you post the data, i.e. your client-side C-arrays, but not the code where you setup your vertex arrays? How are we supposed to tell whether you're feeding the vertex stage properly?